# Convert unsigned char array to char array

Tags: c, hash, hashcode, sha1

I created a C ++ project, but I work with code for CUDA in C. Therefore, I need an example of converting **unsigned char *** to **char ***. Below is an example of getting hash in C ++, but in C code **I will use "malloc" instead of "new"**

*Description of the program:* The hash that needs to be hacked is received at the input of the program. I convert it using the hex_to_sting function and compare the hash computed with the sha1new function

***My goal is*** do a few iterations of the sha1 algorithm.

Example:

1 iteration: word "zzzz" = hash "cb990257247b592eaaed54b84b32d96b7904fd95";

2 iteration: word "cb990257247b592eaaed54b84b32d96b7904fd95" - hash "775a2dae52c3ef080726dd427f81bd482fdf96b5";

*I want to convert the output of sha1new to text format and transfer it again to sha1new*

sha1 algorithm - a little upgraded code from here: https://github.com/mochimodev/cuda-hashing-algos/blob/master/sha1.cu

sha1new() function:

```
__device__ __host__ inline void sha1new(uint8* msg, uint8 length, uint8 sha1[20]) {
    CUDA_SHA1_CTX ctx;
    cuda_sha1_init(&ctx);
    cuda_sha1_update(&ctx, msg, length);
    cuda_sha1_final(&ctx, sha1);
}
```

hex_to_string:

```
void hex_to_string(uint8* msg, size_t msg_sz, char* hex, size_t hex_sz)
{
    memset(msg, '\0', msg_sz);
    for (int i = 0; i < hex_sz; i += 2)
    {
        uint8_t msb = (hex[i + 0] <= '9' ? hex[i + 0] - '0' : (hex[i + 0] & 0x5F) - 'A' + 10);
        uint8_t lsb = (hex[i + 1] <= '9' ? hex[i + 1] - '0' : (hex[i + 1] & 0x5F) - 'A' + 10);
        msg[i / 2] = (msb << 4) | lsb;
    }
}
```

Its work for one sha1 iteration (not output "not equal"):

```
   char* testhash = "cb990257247b592eaaed54b84b32d96b7904fd95";
   char* word = "zzzz";
   unsigned char* sha1hash = new unsigned char[41];
   sha1new((unsigned char*)word, 4, sha1hash);
   uint8 sha1Unhexed[21];
   hex_to_string(sha1Unhexed, 20, testhash, 40);
   for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
   {
       if (sha1Unhexed[i] != sha1hash[i])
           std::cout << "not equal" << std::endl;
   }
```

Comment: You can't convert a char array to an unsigned char array. You can cast it though. But I wonder if you want to cast it, or want to convert byte data to hexadecimal data. Your question is not clear since you intermix C and C++ (it's tagged C but you're using `new`) and we don't know what the `sha1new` function is. Please provide a [mre] and clarify your question in order to get a good answer.

Comment: @wovano Check it now

Comment: `uint8 sha1[20]` It is exactly a sha1 BINARY array. :) What you want is a byte to hex conversion: one byte -> two hex chars. This leads to the length of 20*2 of you initial array.

Comment: @Roberto Caboni I have  #define uint8 unsigned char :)

Comment: @Bishamon, you keep updating your question so it's difficult to answer now. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then clearly explain what you want. Your latest code (at time of writing of this comment) does not work, but requires a completely different answer than what I've already explained.

Comment: @Roberto Caboni i use sha1Unhexed[21] only for input hash conversions

Comment: @wovano I updated the question because it needed more information. if the question is not clear now, then tell me what exactly to fix

Comment: What is the expected output of your application? The SHA1 hash of "zzzz" is cb990257247b592eaaed54b84b32d96b7904fd95 and you're comparing it with 775a2dae52c3ef080726dd427f81bd482fdf96b5

Comment: And the title of your question is "Convert unsigned char array to char array" which seems completely unrelated to your current question

Comment: @wovano yeap, sorry, its misprint. SHA1 hash of "zzzz" - "cb990257247b592eaaed54b84b32d96b7904fd95", SHA1 hash of "cb990257247b592eaaed54b84b32d96b7904fd95" - "775a2dae52c3ef080726dd427f81bd482fdf96b5" (two SHA1 iterations). In first iteration i have correct comparison "cb990257247b592eaaed54b84b32d96b7904fd95" with "cb990257247b592eaaed54b84b32d96b7904fd95". But if i have do two SHA1 iterations (for "775a2dae52c3ef080726dd427f81bd482fdf96b5"), comparison displays "not equal" - thats my problem

Comment: @wovano the question has such a name, because all I need is to convert the unsigned char array to char array and pass it to sha1new again, as previously passed "zzzz" :)

Comment: You can just pass a `unsigned char` as a `char` array. With strict compilation rules it might need a cast, but that's all. However, in your second iteration, do you want to hash the binary result of the first iteration, or the hexadecimal string representation of the first hash result? Like I explained in my answer, you have to distinguish between these two forms. It does not seem logical to me to create a hash of the hexadecimal string, so I expect that that's were the problem is. Are you sure that 775a2dae52c3ef080726dd427f81bd482fdf96b5 is the correct result of two iterations?

Comment: @wovano i use this site for check it: http://www.sha1-online.com/. 1 iteration: word "zzzz" - hash "cb990257247b592eaaed54b84b32d96b7904fd95", 2 iteration: word "cb990257247b592eaaed54b84b32d96b7904fd95" - hash "775a2dae52c3ef080726dd427f81bd482fdf96b5". In second iteration i want to hash the hexadecimal string representation of the first hash result, so i need convert the binary result of the first iteration to hexadecimal string

Comment: Yes, I know that site, but it decodes the TEXT you enter, not the binary hash. So what do you want to achieve? I'll stop commenting now, because this discussion has become way too long. If you'll post a [mre] I might take another look at your question, but otherwise it's up to others to answer your question. Good luck with it.

Comment: @wovano i edit question, please check it

Answer (score 0):

A sha1 hash is 160 bits of information, which can be stored in 20 bytes. Since humans don't read binary data, it is often printed in hexadecimal form, resulting in a string of 40 characters in the range 0-9 and a-f (or A-F).

You have to realize that the hashing algorithm itself works on the binary data. The hexadecimal form is only used for printing (or storing in a text file, etc.).

So when performing multiple iterations of the hash algorithm, you have to use the binary data. Afterwards you can convert it to hexadecimal format.

So, something like this (NB: code is not tested, because I don't have the sha1new function):

```c
char * word = "zzzz";
unsigned char * sha1hash = (unsigned char *)malloc(20);
// first iteration has word as input and yields a hash of 160 bits
sha1new(word, strlen(word), sha1hash);
// following iteraitons have the hash as input and a new has as output
for (int i = 1; i < number_of_iterations; i++) {
   sha1new(sha1hash, 20, sha1hash);
   // NOTE: this only works is the sha1new function accepts the same
   // buffer as input and output, otherwise you'd have to make copies
}

// now print the hash
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
   printf("%02x", (int)sha1hash[i]);
}

// and don't forget to free the memory
free(sha1hash);
sha1hash = NULL;
```

Comment: in my program, the hash that needs to be hacked is input. I made a hash from "zzzz" and a hash from this hash. Now I convert the input hash and compare it with the received hash from "zzzz", but this doesn’t work according to your algorithm. Now I will add this information to the description of the question

Comment: Check description now